# How to eliminate the rows from an array which have common elements at different index position in python?

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have a 2D array of form

```
[[ 1  6]
 [ 2  7]
 [ 5  6]
 [ 6  1]
 [ 6  5]
 [ 7  2]]
```

I want the output of the form

```
[[ 1  6]
 [ 2  7]
 [ 5  6]]
```

How I can get this output?

Comment: I assume you're using NumPy, so I added the [tag:numpy] tag for you. If that's incorrect, you can [edit] to fix it. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using plain Python, but I'm sure there's a more idiomatic way with NumPy.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
    [1, 6],
    [2, 7],
    [5, 6],
    [6, 1],
    [6, 5],
    [7, 2]])

seen = set()
out = []
for row in a:
    elements = frozenset(row)
    if elements not in seen:
        seen.add(elements)
        out.append(row)
print(np.array(out))
```

Output:

```
[[1 6]
 [2 7]
 [5 6]]
```